# Not able to deserialize into java object

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to deserialise JOSN into the given java object but, facing some issue in mapping due to `@JsonProperty`.

When I comment out `@JsonProperty("order_type")` then, it works fine but, I can't comment it out in my actual code.

**POJO Class:**

```
class Abc {
   @JsonProperty("order_type")
   private String orderType;
}
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
Sting str="{\"orderType\":\"Credit\"}"; //assume this is having proper escape character
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.readValue(str, Abc.class);
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code and, how to deserialise it into the given java object.

Comment: The code should be formatted as code and not as text..

Comment: I agree, the code input here is really low quality. Please read [mcve] and show us some code that at least compiles. The above has syntax errors all over the place! You want other people to spend their free time to help you, so you please spend the few minutes it takes to **properly** format/indent your input to us.

Comment: made the changes ,can you now look on to that

Comment: Could you look on to your formatting ? Separate the classe code and the code that map your object. it's hard to read. What kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

> When I commented out @JsonProperty("order_type") then it works fine.

This is because your JSON has the property `orderType` and not, `order_type`.

You'll have to change your JSON input to something like below if you want it to work with your existing code including `@JsonProperty(...)` annotation,

`{\"order_type\":\"Credit\"}`

Comment: Thanks,but Can't we do in any other way as changing to above format is like a naive approach.

Comment: @amitkumar How do you expect Jackson to map `order_type` to `orderType`? You can either remove your `@JsonProperty("order_type")` annotation, change it to `@JsonProperty("orderType")` or change your JSON.